# You do not have permission to perform that action

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites, gs-installable-triggers

I have a time-triggered script that periodically retrieves content from an external source and updates a Google sites page with it. 
According to [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions), the script should be running under my account, which has full assess to that Google site page (tested by manually editing it).
But when I run the script, I get the

> You do not have permission to perform that action.

Why do I not have that permission when running the script, if I can edit the page manually?

Here is the (generalized) script function:

```
function updatePage() {
  var site = 'https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.com/myhome/mypagegroup/mypage';
  var pageName = '/mypagegroup/mypage';

  var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(site);
  var page = site.getChildByName(pageName); //works fine
  Logger.log('page: ' + page.getTitle()); //displays correct page title

  var html = '<p>'; //in actual script, I get html from external source

  Logger.log('html: ' + html);

  page.setHtmlContent(html); //this is where the error is generated ("You do not have permission to perform that action")
};
```

Answer (score 5):

In the script editor, did you choose the function name from the drop down list, and click the run icon?

[image: update Page]

The first time you run it this way, a pop up will display, stating that authorization is needed.  You must give authorization to modify sites.  If that hasn't been done, you'll get an error.

[image: Authorization Required]

Authorize sites:

[image: Manage Sites]

I ran your code, after authorizing the script, and it worked.

You can go into your account, and check what projects you have given permissions to.  You need to choose "Account", and then click "Get Started" in the Security checkup section of the Account settings window.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I went to the security check-up and found authorization:
Google Sites
Manage your sites
Additional access
Connect to an external service

So I removed the authorization to force re-authorization, When I re-ran the script (from the console) it did prompt for authorization, but I still got the same error...

Is here a separate permission that google sites owner has to give to the script? They have given it to my account, and since my script runs under my account, I assumed it would have the same permission, but I can't think of any other reasons for the auth error.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of, is that the site URL that you are using, and/or the pageName variable is wrong, and the code is trying to change a non-existent site or page.  When I tested the code, I just copied the URL from the browser address field of my Google Site:  `https://sites.google.com/site/mysitename/` and I used just the page name, no hierarchy.

Comment: This is an old post, but I was wondering, has someone found a solution? I'm doing something very similar to the original post. For me, my apps script runs for a while (like 2 months) then begins erroring out with "You do not have permission to perform that action." I can go to the Sites announcement page and edit or create a new post no problem. I have unauthorized and re-authorized with no effect. The problem is with apps script/Sites service only. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should look at the Issue Tracker [Link to Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) and search for the same issue.  If you don't find an existing issue, then I'd suggest creating a new issue.  A script should not suddenly loose it's authorization for no reason.  It's interesting that your script only looses authorization to the Sites service, and not anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's an old post. I found a solution for a similar problem of mine. You should add permissions, or scopes: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes