# Google Apps Script suddenly lost the access to Calendar API

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-calendar-api

I have a Google Apps Script that retrieves the events from my Google Calendar and processes them.
It worked fine just around 3-4 hours ago, but at some point it simply stopped working.

The error occurs at line:

```
var calendar = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarsByName('calendar name')[0];
```

The error says "The script doesn't have the permission to perform this action. Required permissions (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly || https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds)".

I checked the quotas at Google Calendar API, but I'm definitely not exceeding the limits set there.

Comment: Have you tried checking these related links: [How do I fix "The script does not have permission...](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/642616?hl=en), [SO 28200857](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200857/), [SO 53381003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381003/), [SO 52274478](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274478/), [SO 49317412](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317412/)

Comment: Thank you. I ended up re-creating the script from scratch and pasting the code into it, and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution would be to explicitly specify the required permissions in the manifests file as described here: ["Authorisation is required to perform that action" message, even after clicking "Allow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491740/authorisation-is-required-to-perform-that-action-message-even-after-clicking)

Simply add the URLs mentioned in the errors to the oauthScopes array.